# Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden' - PowerBi App owns data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, powerbi-embedded

I have a standard MVC application that displays PowerBi reports in an "app owns data" style.  Because we have various clients who cannot see each other's data, it is set up so each client has a behind the scenes accounts that logs them into PowerBi.  It worked great for the 1st 7 accounts we created in Azure, but now that I am trying to add client #8, I get the status code of forbidden on the following line of code:

```
var tokenResponse = await client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroupAsync(GroupId, report.Id, generateTokenRequestParameters);
```

We have assigned a PowerBI Pro license to client #8.  I can log into PowerBi itself just fine as Client #8.

Here's the full block of code that precedes the line in question:

```
using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(ApiUrl), tokenCredentials))
        {
            // Get a list of reports.
            var reports = await client.Reports.GetReportsInGroupAsync(GroupId);

            if (reports.Value.Count < 1)
            {
                reportList.ErrorMessage = "Group has no reports";
                return reportList;
            }

            try
            {

                foreach (Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.Models.Report report in reports.Value)
                {
                    var datasets = await client.Datasets.GetDatasetByIdInGroupAsync(GroupId, report.DatasetId);

                    // Generate Embed Token for reports without effective identities.

                    var generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "view");


                    var tokenResponse = await client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroupAsync(GroupId, report.Id, generateTokenRequestParameters);
```

To reiterate, the code works fine if I log in as an "old" account, but the "new" accounts fail at this line.

Comment: Is this workspace assigned to a dedicated capacity? `GenerateTokenInGroup` [**requires**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers#move-to-production) a dedicated capacity. Pro accounts has [limited number of tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers#development-testing), which are intended for development purposes only.

Comment: We figured this out.  For us we ended up logging into O365 as these new users.